# Unexpected and strange MOSFET behavior

Tags: mosfet

[image]

Va is 10 V, M1 is OFF; Vc and Vd are both 95 mV and M3 and M4 are ON. Good, that is that expected, but why M2 is ON here? The gate of M2 is grounded. Vb measures 735 mV, which is strange!

[image]

Here, I added a resistor to the bottom. Va is the same, as expected; Vb is 5.3 V. Very strange. Vgs for M2 is -5.3 V, how can this MOS still able to turn itself ON? Both VC and VD are about 5 V, but with VD slightly higher than VC.

Comment: Have you considered the body-diode in your thoughts?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

M2 is not on, but its body diode is forward biased.

Here's the actual scheme of an NMOS:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fc4fay.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

In the above picture, D1 is the body diode of M1. When you turn the NMOS on, it shorts the body diode.

Let's look at M2 in your circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fx60Eq.png)</sup>

M2 is off here, but the body diode is forward biased. So the current flows through R2 and the body diode. You'll see that Vb is the forward drop of M2's body diode.

Same thing applies in your second circuit. The current flows through R2, M2's body diode and R5. And the current is determined by
$$
\mathrm{I=\frac{(V1 - V_F)}{(R2+R5)}}
$$.

Comment: Sorry but the usage of units and  square brackets in your equation is totally wrong, If I were you I'd consider having a look here https://www.nist.gov/pml/special-publication-811/nist-guide-si-chapter-7-rules-and-style-conventions-expressing-values

Comment: @carloc Fixed. Thanks for the correction and the resource.